# How do I Group By and Count a column with 2 values at the same time?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called campaign. This is what it looks like:

```
website event type
amazon  imp
amazon  imp
amazon  imp
amazon  click
apple   click
apple   imp
adidas  click
adidas  imp
adidas  click
adidas  imp
```

I want to group it by the different values in the event type column and then count the different values in event type. My table should end up looking like this:

```
website imp click
amazon  3   1
apple   1   1
adidas  2   2
```

How would I go about doing this?

EDIT 14/03/19 :

Where I got to so far :

```
  SELECT a.[webite], case when a.[event_type] = 'imp' then 1 end as 'imp', case when a.[event_type] = 'click' then 1 end as 'click'
  FROM [campaign] as a
  INNER JOIN [campaign] as b 
  ON a.[webite] = b.[webite]
```

Comment: Have you tried from yourself please include that query also in your question.

Comment: Added to original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation :

```
select website,
       sum(case when event = 'imp' then 1 else 0 end) as imp,
       sum(case when event = 'click' then 1 else 0 end) as click
from campaign c
group by website;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `PIVOT` with `COUNT`

```
DECLARE @SampleTable TABLE (website VARCHAR(10), [event type]  VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @SampleTable VALUES
('amazon' ,'imp'),
('amazon' ,'imp'),
('amazon' ,'imp'),
('amazon' ,'click'),
('apple' ,'click'),
('apple' ,'imp'),
('adidas' ,'click'),
('adidas' ,'imp'),
('adidas' ,'click'),
('adidas' ,'imp')


SELECT * FROM @SampleTable
PIVOT (COUNT([event type]) FOR [event type] IN ([imp], [click])) PVT
```

Result:

```
website    imp         click
---------- ----------- -----------
adidas     2           2
amazon     3           1
apple      1           1
```

Answer (score 1):

Out of the available other option as answered by another user you can also try the below query.

```
select a.website, imp, click from(
     select website, count(eventtype) as imp
     from test a where a.eventtype = 'imp' group by website
)a 
inner join (
     select website, count(eventtype) as click
     from test b where b.eventtype = 'click' group by website  
)b on a.website = b.website
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/BEDXAC49228)